# Cannot get the value of an "input" element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test. I need to get the text inside an input element:

```
<table class="boundaryFormAdd">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="id_name" type="text" style="margin-top: 5px">
          </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

but as you can see it neither has a `value` attribute nor any inner text.

I have tried:

1) elementname.getAttribute("innerHTML")

2) elementname.getText()

Comment: Don't know selenium, but the text of an `<input>` field is stored in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `input` tag does not have any closing tag like `</input>`. They do not hold anything inside. These are called void elements. So `getText()` ,`getAttribute("innerHTML")` - will not return anything.

You can access other attributes of input element by using `getAttribute(attrname)` method.

To get the value, try with `driver.findElement(..).getAttribute("value")`

Comment: why did it work when there is not "value" in the input attributes?

Comment: by default value="". i am sure there is a javascript code which sets the value at run time.

Comment: what other attributes a webelement may have?